# Cycling in Africa

Tags: regional

I know there are initiatives like World Bicycle Relief and Bikes Without Borders in Africa, but what else is being done in relation to cycling in Africa?

Aren't there any local initiatives to make people bike, local bicycle brands, etc.?

Comment: I need the regional tag is deprecated, but I couldn't add a tag like Africa because I'm new here.

Comment: You realise Africa is a continent, and it's bigger than the Americas combined? There's everything from the ludicrously white and rich diamond industry in South Africa to the US-backed dictatorship of Egypt to the 'everyone's having a war' of the Democratic Republic of Congo.

Comment: Our local bike co-op has helped fill a shipping container of MTBs for Mozambique. Probably 400-500 bikes in there plus a bunch of spares and tools.

Comment: This group collects bikes in Australia and NZ and sends them to Namibia and Zambia http://www.bicyclesforhumanity.com/

Comment: Do realized Africa is a continent etc., but I'm still looking for bike initiatives from everywhere in Africa.

Comment: Maybe start by looking for bicycle initiatives on the continent you're on, then see if those would work in Africa.

Answer (score 3):

You can read about the Bicycling Empowerment Network Namibia here http://www.bennamibia.org/  We are a local organisation that helps establish bicycle shops.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of initiatives I'm looking for.